# Regex to extract search terms is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, regex, ecmascript-6

I have the test string
ti: harry Potter OR kw: magic AND sprint: title OR ti: HARRY

and want the output as

```
["ti: harry Potter OR kw:", "kw: magic AND sprint:", "sprint: title OR ti:", "ti: HARRY"]
```

but the output I am getting is

```
["ti: harry Potter OR kw:", "kw: magic AND sprint:", "nt: title OR ti:", "ti: HARRY"]
```

It is taking only 2 characters before the colon
The regex I am using is

```
const match = /[a-z0-9]{2}:.*?($|[a-z0-9]{2}:)/g;
```

and I am extracting it and putting it in an array

I tried replacing it with `/[a-z0-9]+:.*?($|[a-z0-9]+:)/g;` but when I increase index and add the strings to parsed, it does it weirdly (This is included in code as well)

I tried changing the {2} to n and that is also not working as expected.

```
const parsed = [];
const match = /[a-z0-9]{2}:.*?($|[a-z0-9]{2}:)/g;
const message = "ti: harry Potter OR kw: magic AND sprint: title OR ti: HARRY";
let next = match.exec(message);
while (next) {
  parsed.push(next[0]);
  match.lastIndex = next.index + 1;
  next = match.exec(message);
  console.log("next again", next);
}

console.log("parsed", parsed);
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/regex-forked-6op514?file=/src/index.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the desired matches, you might use  a pattern where you would also optionally match `AND` or `OR` and get the match in capture group 1, which is denoted be `m[1]` in the example code.

```
\b(?=([a-z0-9]+:.*?(?: (?:AND|OR) [a-z0-9]+:|$)))
```

In parts, the pattern matches:

- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial match
- `(?=` Positive lookahead to assert what is on the right is

  - `(` Capture **group 1**

    - `[a-z0-9]+:`
    - `.*?` Match any char except a newline as least as possible
    - `(?:` Non capture group

      - `(?:AND|OR) [a-z0-9]+:` Match either `AND` or `OR` followed by a space and 1+ times a char a-z0-9 and `:`
      - `|` Or
      - `$` Assert the end of the string
    - `)` Close non capture group
  - `)` Close group 1
- `)` Close the lookahead

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AQ67IB/1).

```js
const regex = /\b(?=([a-z0-9]+:.*?(?: (?:AND|OR) [a-z0-9]+:|$)))/gm;
const str = `ti: harry Potter OR kw: magic AND sprint: title OR ti: HARRY`;
const result = Array.from(str.matchAll(regex), m => m[1]);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Can this be expanded to take care of this as well `ti: harry Potter kw: magic sprint: title ti: HARRY` ? A Non boolean term?

Comment: @keerti Like this? `\b(?=([a-z0-9]+:.*?(?:[a-z0-9]+:|$)))` https://regex101.com/r/bw49bs/1